Backing Up WSL Environment: Alternatives to Image Backups
I'm currently using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) for development, and I've been using image backups to backup my WSL environment. However, I've noticed that image backups consume a significant amount of memory, especially as my WSL environment grows in size. Are there alternative methods for backing up WSL environments that use less memory or disk space?
Are there alternative methods for backing up WSL environments that use less memory or disk space?
